# Drawing new binary classification boundaries given a change in some parameters

Tags: classification

The basic binary classification algorithm determines a fixed decision boundary once it has been trained on some collection of samples. Does there exist a binary classification algorithm that re-draws the decision boundary based on some parameter $z$? The goal is to obtain a plot of this new decision boundary.

Suppose that our samples are points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and points of class #1 are simply clustered together into a disc in the $xy$-plane, while the points of class #2 lie outside this disc. Now consider another parameter $z$ that causes the points to spread out (and form larger discs) or contract (and form smaller discs). This additional parameter could be viewed as the height – and the collection of samples for different $z$ values happens to form sphere, for example.

Does there exist a binary classification algorithm that takes in two inputs: one would be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (a point on our disc) and another would be a parameter $z$. The goal would be to have a function that draws the decision boundary for new values of $z$, given some training data for specific values of $z$.

Comment: I think you are looking for SVMs .

Comment: Maybe have a look at Ch. 12 in ESL (Support Vector Machines and Flexible Discriminants) https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf

Comment: Maybe have a look at Ch. 12 in ESL (Support Vector Machines and Flexible Discriminants) https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf